# Need to show X-axis labels on subchart selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

The [c3js.org/samples/options_subchart](https://c3js.org/samples/options_subchart.html) show the problem: the x-scale have no labels when navigating by a window selected by the subchart.

How to add x-axis labels when in this dynamic-window view?

---

### Notes

This is the chart with no window selected,

[image]

and this is the chart with a window selected:

[image]

see?  **No x-axis labels**, even when it exists (a different day in this case) for each point.

---

EDIT with @schustischuster's  sample (enhanced with some data more)  http://jsfiddle.net/xodyq92n/

[image]

```
 // more x-axis data to show the problem
 ['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-04',
       '2013-01-05', '2013-01-06', '2013-01-07', '2013-01-08',
       '2013-01-09', '2013-01-10', '2013-01-11', '2013-01-12',
       '2013-01-13'
 ]
```

---

Note after @buræquete clues about `culling: false` and subchart control *onbrush*. My **real life data have ~600 items for x-axis**, so no-culling causes a big blur:

[image]

Then, the problem can be summarized as a **need for "intermediary culling"**.

Comment: In the C3.js subchart option @ https://c3js.org/samples/options_subchart.html both x-axis show labels when a region is selected. Maybe you could provide a working example of your chart to find out what's going on? I have created a fiddle exmple for time series data with subchart option and it does work indeed http://jsfiddle.net/xhb1jp4w/

Comment: Thanks @schustischuster, I edited. I need to see more labels, I not see the x-axis labels.

Comment: It seems to be an open issue https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/835

Comment: Thanks @schustischuster, it seems the "unfortunate answer", **it is a C3 bug**...  Perhaps will be easy  to introduce a option/parameter for *"enhance label density"* when user see need for it: I will offer some bounty, to encourage a solution.

Comment: PS: [plot.ly/javascript](https://plot.ly/javascript/) is using old D3 version 3, and is so complex and heavy (and not-all free)... **C3js seems the best** "plug-and-play" chart lib over D3, but, [seems developers abandoning it](https://github.com/dimagi/commcare-android/pull/824#issuecomment-510882633).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[previous solution with culling turned off](http://jsfiddle.net/g8cbzd96/)

Rather than having `culling` turned off, and then drop the excess labels, I keep it enabled, and force-displaying the labels in the main chart when zoomed in. This can be viewed on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95zo60xu/1/).

Or check the snippet below;

```js
const TICK_WIDTH = 35;
var chart = document.getElementById("c3_chart");
var visibilityThreshold = chart.clientWidth / TICK_WIDTH;

function addLabelToTicks() {
  var allTicks = document.querySelectorAll("#c3_chart .c3-axis-x.c3-axis > g");
  var visibleTicks = Array.from(allTicks)
    .filter(tick => !tick.querySelector("line[x1='0'][x2='0'][y2='0']"));
  if (visibleTicks.length < visibilityThreshold) {
    visibleTicks.forEach(tick => tick.querySelector("text").style.display = "block");
  }
}

var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#c3_chart',
  data: {
    x: 'x',
    //        xFormat: '%Y%m%d', // 'xFormat' can be used as custom format of 'x'
    columns: [
      ['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-04', '2013-01-05', '2013-01-06',
        '2013-01-07', '2013-01-08', '2013-01-09', '2013-01-10', '2013-01-11', '2013-01-12', '2013-01-13', '2013-01-14', '2013-01-15', '2013-01-16', '2013-01-17', '2013-01-18', '2013-01-19',
        '2013-01-20', '2013-01-21', '2013-01-22', '2013-01-23', '2013-01-24', '2013-01-25', '2013-01-26'
      ],
      ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 160, 150, 160, 150, 200, 160, 170, 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 160, 150, 160, 150, 200, 160, 170],
      ['data2', 130, 340, 200, 500, 250, 350, 320, 200, 500, 250, 350, 300, 310, 130, 340, 200, 500, 250, 350, 320, 200, 500, 250, 350, 300, 310]
    ]
  },
  subchart: {
    show: true,
    onbrush: addLabelToTicks
  },
  axis: {
    x: {
      type: 'timeseries',
      tick: {
        rotate: 25,
        //culling: false,
        format: '%Y-%m-%d'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.c3 svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif
}

.c3 line,
.c3 path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
}


/* In this example I changed the line color to red for c3_chart_2 */

#c3_chart_2.c3 line,
#c3_chart_2.c3 path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
}

.c3 text {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none
}

.c3-bars path,
.c3-event-rect,
.c3-legend-item-tile,
.c3-xgrid-focus,
.c3-ygrid {
  shape-rendering: crispEdges
}

.c3-chart-arc path {
  stroke: #fff
}

.c3-chart-arc text {
  fill: #fff;
  font-size: 13px
}

.c3-grid line {
  stroke: #aaa
}

.c3-grid text {
  fill: #aaa
}

.c3-xgrid,
.c3-ygrid {
  stroke-dasharray: 3 3
}

.c3-text.c3-empty {
  fill: gray;
  font-size: 2em
}

.c3-line {
  stroke-width: 1px
}

.c3-circle._expanded_ {
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke: #fff
}

.c3-selected-circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2px
}

.c3-bar {
  stroke-width: 0
}

.c3-bar._expanded_ {
  fill-opacity: .75
}

.c3-target.c3-focused {
  opacity: 1
}

.c3-target.c3-focused path.c3-line,
.c3-target.c3-focused path.c3-step {
  stroke-width: 2px
}

.c3-target.c3-defocused {
  opacity: .3!important
}

.c3-region {
  fill: #4682b4;
  fill-opacity: .1
}

.c3-brush .extent {
  fill-opacity: .1
}

.c3-legend-item {
  font-size: 12px
}

.c3-legend-item-hidden {
  opacity: .15
}

.c3-legend-background {
  opacity: .75;
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #d3d3d3;
  stroke-width: 1
}

.c3-tooltip-container {
  z-index: 10
}

.c3-tooltip {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  empty-cells: show;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 12px -9px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 7px 7px 12px -9px #777;
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 12px -9px #777;
  opacity: .9
}

.c3-tooltip tr {
  border: 1px solid #CCC
}

.c3-tooltip th {
  background-color: #aaa;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #FFF
}

.c3-tooltip td {
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-left: 1px dotted #999
}

.c3-tooltip td>span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 6px
}

.c3-tooltip td.value {
  text-align: right
}

.c3-area {
  stroke-width: 0;
  opacity: .2
}

.c3-chart-arcs-title {
  dominant-baseline: middle;
  font-size: 1.3em
}

.c3-chart-arcs .c3-chart-arcs-background {
  fill: #e0e0e0;
  stroke: none
}

.c3-chart-arcs .c3-chart-arcs-gauge-unit {
  fill: #000;
  font-size: 16px
}

.c3-chart-arcs .c3-chart-arcs-gauge-max,
.c3-chart-arcs .c3-chart-arcs-gauge-min {
  fill: #777
}

.c3-chart-arc .c3-gauge-value {
  fill: #000
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <br><br>
  <div id="c3_chart" style="width: 90%; height: 270px"></div>
```

**How it works?** 
The labels are always generated, but kept hidden with `display:none` css configuration. So my solution is to always keep track of the # of visible ticks in the top chart, and when it is below some threshold (e.g. zoomed in), then always display these hidden labels (`display:block`).

**Warnings**

- This function might not work when you update c3 & d3 for some class names, or hierarchy of objects might change, thus requiring an update of the logic in the function. At least I kept the function pure js so no trouble with 3rd party version change affecting it.

Comment: The `culling`  property is a good clue, but not yet a solution: makes a big blur at axis (both subchart and main chart). We need an "intermediary *culling* effect". My data have ~600 items for x-axis.

Comment: @PeterKrauss Did you try the second fiddle? Filtering the ticks for the subchart? The mess in the top chart should go away after zooming in, but you can apply the same logic to the top chart as well, like if there are more than n ticks, then apply the same filtering to top one as well? What do you think? It is a bit jittery though...

Comment: Thanks, now I see, sorry. You are heading in the right direction! ... I will try to do some fine adjustments and come back tomorrow with an opinion. Seems good, deserve a vote!

Comment: Hi, I have upvoted and seems there are no competitor for the bounty (3 votes already guarantee half, but we must wait for the period for other answers before award). Suggestions for your code and answer: **1.** include in the answer text the  `addLabelToTicks()` code, that is the kernel of the solution; **2.** Ideal to replace the global document of `mainChartTicks = document.querySelectorAll(etc)` by some C3 internal pointer to *bindto*.  **3.** the value 20 of `mainTickCount > 20` seems magic, perhaps ideal is a parameter.

Comment: Does this work for a bar chart? I cannot seem to get it to work.